# sms confirmation code too long

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, registration

I'm trying to register as a developer, and was asked for my cell phone number.

I got the SMS code, but it is 8 characters long, and the textbox allows for only 6 characters code.

How can I enter the code I've got?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

While I was able to reproduce your issue, the SMS that I received while trying to verify my identity at the [phone confirmation Page](https://www.facebook.com/confirmphone.php) I did also receive a link that served as a secondary mean of verifying it instead of manually inserting the code and works.

Comment: I tried using the confirmation page, but it ended up asking again for the SMS code, so that didn't help...

Comment: well the link didn't work for me but I just edited the source and changed the maxlength from 6 to 8 (double face palm!)

Comment: So nice, i feel like a hacker now @ryanoasis

Comment: This happened to me too. I tapped the link instead of using the code and it worked. Facebook's level of idiocy is laughable sometimes.